# okta - asp.net web forms - how do I prevent an unauthorized user from navigating to a secure web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, okta

I am trying to add okta to a very old ASP.Net Web Forms app.

I am following this demo: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/08/29/secure-webforms-with-openidconnect-okta

And I intergraded the changes into my solution.

However, now I want to secure specific web pages.  I don’t want anyone to be able to navigate to specific pages unless they are authenticated.   If they do attempt to navigate to a secure page, I want them to be sent to okta to sign in.

I added the below code, which is similar to code from the demo above. And it seems to work.

```
    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        return;
    }
```

However, I don’t want to add this code to every page.

In the past when I integrated okta in an ASP.NET MVC app, I would add the [Authenticate] attribute to the controller.  That would give me the desired effect.

Any suggestions on how I get the desired result for an ASP.Net Web Forms app?

One option, which is not ideal, is the place the code in my Master Page. The problem is I have a few Master pages, so I will have to duplicate the code.

I know Web Forms can use Forms Authentication. And then use the following configuration for force the user to a LogIn page.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" />
    </authentication>
```

But, I am not using Forms Authentication. I am using okta.

Finally, I was thinking about using a custom HttpModule / Handler. However, when I tried that, the custom module runs before Startup.cs.   Startup.cs contains the code to initialize okta and the owin context.  As a result, when the custom module runs, GetOwinContext fails.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What I've done before is to create multiple MasterPages: one for base layout, one for authenticated pages, and potentially one for anonymous users depending on your needs. Then in the MasterPage for auth pages, add that chunk of code to the `Page_Load()` method.

Comment: @derekmckinnon After discussing this issue with an developer in my company that has experience with okta and web forms, we basically decided to do the same thing.  Thanks for confirming this decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@derekmckinnon After discussing this issue with an developer in my company that has experience with okta and web forms, we basically decided to do the same thing. Thanks for confirming this decision.